# Use Global Variable In Same File As It's Declared?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to use a global variable in the same file that it is declared?

The following code does not throw a compiletime error:

```
declare global {
  const something = "something goes here";
}
export default {
  somethingElse: something + " else"
}
```

However, it seems to be causing an 'undefined variable' error in the same file and every other file I use it in.

Comment: Sure, why not? If it doesn't throw a runtime error, and it doesn't throw a compile time error, and it actually does what you want, then by definition it works?

Comment: The declare here is only a type, but you still need to create the global.  But then why not just do `const something = ""`.  IOW: why are you using declare here?

Comment: Well, I was having an issue where it wouldn't work. The cost was being assigned an enum in the same file and even though IDE did not catch anything, it was erroring with as undefined at runtime. Sorry I mistyped the post. Changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript's `declare` syntax is used to declare variables that *already exist globally* in the context of a module. For instance, in a web application where variables might be coming from `<script>` tags that TypeScript isn't aware of, said variables and their types can be `declare`d so that their use can be type checked.

Therefore, TypeScript wouldn't warn you about `something` being undefined, as it expects the variable to already have been declared elsewhere, and your `declare global {}` block to be informing it of said declaration.